# Set page count on dynamic pages & maintain page visit count in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to know the logic of this. I am not posting any code because I don't know what is the logic behind this so please pardon. I have a page call dynamicPage. This page is connected with database & everytime details of particular things gets fetched according to users selected. Now I want to track How many time particular thing is visited.

e.g.

1. Hospital1
2. Hospital2
3. Hospital3

If user clicks on Hospital2 then it's count get increased by one & so on..

I made this site http://www.brandstik.in/Music here many products are listed. Now I want to see how many times particular products is viewed.

Comment: when you click on the items, you are redirecting to another page where you load details of the product, right? you have to increase the count for related method there

Comment: @AshkanSirous if I set count then it's value will get increase by 1 on each page refresh that I don't want. It should get increase only if unique request . What is the method to define unique request from client?

Answer (score 0):

You need something between clicking on the product link and loading the detail page. There are lots of ways to do that. One of the easiest ones is to have a method between you clicked on the link and loading the detail page. So the simplest solution that I can suggest is to have an action (if it is MVC) or a simple method on detail page, increase the count and then redirect to the original one. So lets say your code is in MVC and you have a method like this on dynamic page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("@item.productName", "Index", "Products", new {id = "@item.id"}))
```

and you have this code in your products controller:

```
public class ProductsController:Controller
{
  Public ActionResult Index(int Id)
  {
  ...some code to load and return the productDetails
  }
}
```

Then you need to add a method to add to the count and then redirects to the original method. so your controller will be like this:

```
public class ProductsController:Controller
{
  Public ActionResult Index(int Id)
  {
  //some code to load and return the productDetails
  }
  public ActionResult IncreaseProductCount(int Id)
  {
   //increase the count
    return RedirectToAction("Index",new{Id=Id});
   }
}
```

And then on the dynamic page view change your code to call the new method instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("@item.productName", "IncreaseProductCount", "Products", new {id = "@item.id"}))
```